# Migration of data 

Tags: sql, data-migration

I want to migrate the data from one table to another.  Here Table1 has identity column.
I require Table2 to have same data and identity.

How can I do this?

Comment: It would be helpful if you specified which database product you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, this is very basic, but would this work?

```
SET IDENTITY INSERT dbo.Table2 ON

INSERT INTO dbo.Table2
SELECT ...
FROM dbo.Table1

SET IDENTITY INSERT dbo.Table2 OFF
```

Comment: Try this in collaboration with mite and then you don't have to worry about how to write your migrations because you can do anything that sql can do.  https://github.com/soitgoes/mite